# How to pass a parameter from Batch file to a function inside a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameter-passing

I have a Batch file which will call a Powershell Script :

**BATCH FILE :**
    @ECHO OFF 
    powershell ..\PowerShellScript.ps1

The powershell script in turn has a function which expects a parameter :

**POWERSHELL SCRIPT:**

```
function PSFunction([string]$Parameter1)
{
Write-Host $Parameter1
}
```

Lets say i have a value : VALUE1 which needs to be passed from the batch File while calling the PowerShellScript.ps1, how do I pass it to the function PSFunction so that my output is VALUE1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

modify your script to look like the following

```
function PSFunction([string]$Parameter1)
{
  Write-Host $Parameter1
}

PSFunction $args[0]
```

and from the batch file, it would look like

```
powershell ..\PowerShellScript.ps1 VALUE1
```

Comment: and how do I pass the parameter value "VALUE1" from the Batch file ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the -Command switch to tell powershell.exe to interpret a string as if it were typed at a PowerShell prompt. In your case, the string could dot-source PowerShellScript.ps1 (to import it into the new powershell.exe environment) and then call PSFunction with VALUE1 as a parameter:

```
set VALUE1=Hello World
powershell.exe -command ". ..\PowerShellScript.ps1; PSFunction '%VALUE1%'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Defining a function in a Powershell script does *not* execute the function. If you want that, then your script might need to look like that:

```
function PSFunction([string]$Parameter1)
{
  Write-Host $Parameter1
}
PSFunction "some string"
```

From within the script you still have a dynamic `$args` variable that gets any parameters you passed to the script. So

```
function PSFunction([string]$Parameter1)
{
  Write-Host $Parameter1
}
PSFunction $args[0]
```

will pass the first parameter you gave on the commandline on to the function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you simple should choose what to use - batch files or PowerShell:) PowerShell is more powerful, but batch files are easier to create (especially with [Dr.Batcher](http://www.drbatcher.com)) and can be run anywhere.